# using rewrite condition with allow and Satisfy directive

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to create a rule that allows only the https request to be prompted for user credentials and the http request to be redirected .

```
SetEnvIfNoCase IS_SSL .*yes.* HTTPS_REQUEST
<Files *>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "MyFirstPage"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /indexing/.pwd
    Require valid-user 
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from env!=HTTPS_REQUEST
    Satisfy All
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTPS_REQUEST} off [NC]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/Mydata.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}/x1/Mydata.php [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

The above code is prompting for the password for both http and https request . Can you please suggest

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to change "All" to "Any"

```
Satisfy Any
```

That way if the `env!=HTTPS_REQUEST` is true, the `Require valid-user` doesn't need to be satisfied.

Comment: I changed from All to Any and the result is that I get 301 for http request as expected but for https it does not prompt me for password

Comment: I am using 2.2.22 version